# Using RecyclerView in ScrollView with CollapsingToolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I'm having an issue trying to build a layout where I have a CollapsingToolbar and a Scrollview

The ScrollView contains two CardViews and a RecyclerView
The CollapsingToolbar consists of an image, a title and no buttons for the moment

[Activity Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJqSL.png)

[Content Layout (The ScrollView is missing android:fillViewport="true")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE426.png)

With these layouts everything is alright except for the scrolling of course (the parallax doesn't work if I scroll on the cardviews which is annoying)

Here's the Adapter

```
public class HorariosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorariosAdapter.HorarioViewHolder> {
public static class HorarioViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    TextView horaDesde;

    HorarioViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvHorario);
        horaDesde = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHora);
    }
}

List<Horario> horarios;

HorariosAdapter(List<Horario> pHorarios){
    this.horarios = pHorarios;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return horarios.size();
}

@Override
public HorarioViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rvhorarios, viewGroup, false);
    HorarioViewHolder hvh = new HorarioViewHolder(v);
    return hvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HorarioViewHolder horarioViewHolder, int i) {
    horarioViewHolder.horaDesde.setText(horarios.get(i).getHoraDesde());
}
```

}

Over here we have the Activity

```
public class DetalleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
final String EXTRA_ITEM = "Complejo";

private TextView txtDireccion;
private ImageView imgThumbnail;
private RecyclerView rvHorarios;

private HorariosAdapter adapter;
public DetalleActivity CustomListView = null;
private Cancha complejoSeleccionado;
private Horario horario;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    complejoSeleccionado = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_ITEM);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle);
    setToolbar(complejoSeleccionado.getComplejo().toString());

    txtDireccion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDireccion);
    imgThumbnail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);

    txtDireccion.setText(complejoSeleccionado.getDireccion());

    String lowerImagen = complejoSeleccionado.getImagen().toLowerCase();
    int idImagen = getResources().getIdentifier(lowerImagen, "drawable", getPackageName());
    imgThumbnail.setImageResource(idImagen);

    rvHorarios = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvHorarios);
    rvHorarios.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    rvHorarios.setLayoutManager(llm);

    CustomListView = this;

    horario = new Horario();
    horario.initializeData();

    adapter = new HorariosAdapter(horario.horarios);
    rvHorarios.setAdapter(adapter);

    rvHorarios.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detalle, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_search:
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void setToolbar(String titulo)
{
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (complejoSeleccionado.getComplejo().toString() != null) {toolbar.setTitle(titulo);}

    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_arrow);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(a);
        }
    });
}
```

}

I've read about NestedScrollView but I don't think it would solve my problem
I also tried TouchHandlers but to no use

**Question**

How can I put all these three together and scroll them together?

EDIT 1: I know I shouldn't be using a RecyclerView inside a ScrollView, a possible solution could be to separate them in different tabs?

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is parallax effect. [This library will give you good idea about how to achieve that](https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview)

Comment: I already used parallax, I need to fix that effect when I scroll on the CardViews